# 'InvalidRequest URL query parameters are not allowed' Django-oauth2 500 error

Tags: python-3.x, angular, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, pkce

Prefix: I am new to django.

Stack: oAuth2 + PKCE protocol, Angular, Django-oauth2-toolkit + REST

Keep getting:

```
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidRequestError: (invalid_request) URL query parameters are not allowed <oauthlib.Request SANITIZED>
```

No error specifics with regards the contents of the request.

when I hit the django oauth2 server with a pkce formatted POST request in Angular, e.g

```
 requestToken(code: string, state: string) {
    const clientState = sessionStorage.getItem('pkce-state');
    if (clientState !== state) {
      console.error('States do not match!');
    }
    const verifier = sessionStorage.getItem('pkce-verifier');

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/o/token/',
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
      },
      {
        params:
          new HttpParams()
            .set('grant_type', 'authorization_code')
            .set('code', code)
            .set('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard')
            .set('client_id', 'CLIENT_ID')
            .set('state', state)
            .set('verifier', verifier)
      });
    }
```

Not sure what is going wrong.

P.S nothing looks encoded when the request is printed in the django log. The challenge and verifier are working otherwise, the error would indicate so.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that removing httpParams and adding the params as body does not throw error 500. Now I have another error, but the request format is more accurate at least.

```
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/o/token/',
  {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard',
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
    code,
    state,
    verifier
  },
  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
  },
);
```